# Mapping multiple nested arrays in JSON

Tags: json, reactjs, dictionary

I'm new to React, I am trying to map JSON-formatted text containing nested arrays in it like this:

```
{
  "shipments": [
{
    "id": "S1000",
    "name": "T-shirts from Shanghai to Hamburg",
    "cargo": [
        {
            "type": "Fabric",
            "description": "1000 Blue T-shirts",
            "volume": "2"
        }, 
        {
            "type": "Fabric",
            "description": "2000 Green T-shirts",
            "volume": "3"
        }
    ],
    "mode": "sea",
    "type": "FCL",
    "destination": "Saarbrücker Str. 38, 10405 Berlin",
    "origin": "Shanghai Port",
    "services": [
        {
            "type": "customs"
        }
    ],
    "total": "1000",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "userId": "U1000"
}, 
{
    "id": "S1001",
    "name": "New spring collection",
    "cargo": [
        {
            "type": "Furniture",
            "description": "300 Tables",
            "volume": "20"
        }, 
        {
            "type": "Furniture",
            "description": "1500 Chairs",
            "volume": "15"
        }
    ],
    "mode": "sea",
    "type": "FCL",
    "destination": "Saarbrücker Str. 38, 10405 Berlin",
    "origin": "Ningbo port",
    "services": [
        {
            "type": "customs"
        }, 
        {
            "type": "insurance",
            "value": "100"
        }
    ],
    "total": "3000",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "userId": "U1002"
},
}
```

> What I am trying to achieve is to map through this and show the details in a table. I have tried mapping this way:

```
         {
                shipments.map((item, i) => (
                    (typeof(item) == 'array') ? 
                        item.map((subitem, i) => (
                            <tr key={item.id}>
                                <td>{item.id}</td>
                                <td>{ item.cargo.type} </td>
                                <td>{ item.services.value} </td>
                            </tr>
                        )) 
                        :
                    null
                ))
            }
```

**another possible solution was something like this:**

```
`shipments.map((item) => {
    console.log('first loop')
    Object.keys(item).filter(key=>{
        let value = item[key];
        if(Array.isArray(value)){ 
            value.map(subitem=>{
                console.log(subitem.type)
            })
        }
 })
})`
```

but I am not able to solve it. A reusable solution will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just pasted that JSON into a validator and it is invalid so might want to check that first

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear exactly what you want the output to be, but let me explain what's happening with the data and hopefully you can modify that to suit your needs:

Mapping over shipments is going to give you an object e.g. the first `item` you get back will be:

```
{
    "id": "S1000",
    "name": "T-shirts from Shanghai to Hamburg",
    "cargo": [
        {
            "type": "Fabric",
            "description": "1000 Blue T-shirts",
            "volume": "2"
        }, 
        {
            "type": "Fabric",
            "description": "2000 Green T-shirts",
            "volume": "3"
        }
    ],
    "mode": "sea",
    "type": "FCL",
    "destination": "Saarbrücker Str. 38, 10405 Berlin",
    "origin": "Shanghai Port",
    "services": [
        {
            "type": "customs"
        }
    ],
    "total": "1000",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "userId": "U1000"
}
```

You can access data from inside here that is just a string directly, you don't need to do it by mapping over the item, you just access the values directly e.g.

```
shipments.map((item, i) => (
  <tr key={item.id}>
      <td>{item.id}</td>
  </tr>
))
```

If you know that an item is an array, you can then map over that, so to expand your example:

```
shipments.map((item, i) => (
  <tr key={item.id}>
    <td>{item.id}</td>
    {item.cargo.map(cargoItem => {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <td>{cargoItem.type}</td>
          <td>{cargoItem.volume}</td>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    })}
  </tr>
));
```

If you want to do this dynamically, you can make use of something like `Object.values` and check the type before mapping over that or displaying it if it's a string e.g.

```
shipments.map(item => (
  // For each shipment create a row
  <tr key={item.id}>
    {/* For each of the keys, get its value e.g. S1000, T-Shirts 
        from Shanghai to Hamburg, an array of cargo */}
    {Object.values(item).map(subitem => {
      // If the subitem is an array (like cargo) then map over 
      // it and return something for each item
      if (Array.isArray(subitem)) {
        return subitem.map(d => {
          // ...
        });
      } else {
        // Otherwise just return the string
        return <td>{subitem}</td>;
      }
    })}
  </tr>
));
```

Comment: Thanks Bro... I wanted to get it dynamically, I got the idea from here, Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First one this cant (typeof(item) == 'array') get array because of when we map any array it get object not a array.

```js
 {
    itemData.map((item, i)=>{
       return(
           <div key={i}>
                {(item.shipments || []).map(item => {
                  return (
                    <tr key={item.id}>
                      <td>{item.id}</td>
                      <td>{item.cargo.map(p => p.type).toString()} </td>
                      <td>{item.services.map(p => p.value).toString()} </td>
                    </tr>
                  );
                })}
        </div>
      )
      })      
 }
```

Comment: 1. format the code 2. explain why the code answers the question